# Laravel Http Client - How to upload file to linkedin Assets API

Tags: php, laravel-5, linkedin-api

I wanted to upload a file using Laravel HTTP Client, but I'm not able to understand how to work or attach media to LinkedIn. And moreover, LinkedIn API does not even give back any response after upload this becomes even harder for me to figure out where I went wrong.

LinkedIn documentation gives an example using the curl command. When I uploaded a file using the curl command it worked!. And also through postman using the PUT method and body as a binary file, it worked.

Below is LinkedIn Doc under the "Upload the Image" section an example is given for bash.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?tabs=http#upload-the-image.

```
curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1"
```

So, I want to achieve the above curl request in Laravel HTTP Client.

Below is the small piece of code I'm trying to achieve upload functionality

```
   Http::attach('file', file_get_contents($request->file('file')), 'perfidious.jpg')
            ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $oauth2_token,
                'Content-Type' => $file->getMimeType(),
            ])->put('https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C4E22AQFyx5-WPFqU4w/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJDUuJEebKdjgAAAYAIF2PvtGz3bIfDzdyIAomflRbj4jD-Z1lcfP-7NQ&app=201094746&sync=1&v=beta&ut=1S4fxf2p45tWc1')
            ->json();
```

The flow

1. To include attachments in a post at first you have to register for the attachment by connecting to the below API Url. The API returns back a response with a uploadUrl and id for the attachment.

   https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload
2. The "uploadUrl" from the above response is used to upload our image file which gives back only a 201 status code.
3. And at last the "id" which we got from step 1 is used as a reference in post API request containing message and attachment id as the body.

What I did is step 2 using bash and next step 3 normal API request either through postman or Laravel HTTP Client. I was able to see the post on my LinkedIn page. But when I performed **step 2** using Laravel HTTP client "**attach**" method and next step 3. It didn't work and never showed the post.

What I know from Laravel Docs is "file_get_contents" method reads file data as a string maybe I need to do it in binary.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Please, anyone, help me guide on how to do it as I have very minimal knowledge in PHP and Laravel. Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem / error ?

Comment: Hi @Eric, I have updated the question let me know what else info I can provide you. Thanks!

Comment: Is the file $request->file('file') saved locally ?

Comment: @Eric No, I'm not saving it locally.

Comment: I don't think you can upload from URLs

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
$upload = file_get_contents($yourFileUrl);
Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken"])
    ->withBody($upload, '')
    ->put($uploadUrlFromLinkedin);
```

Comment: And why does the asker need to do this? Try to avoid 'code-only' answers, instead explain why the code fixes the askers' problem. Perhaps read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by SO.